# format-table -autosize not working when executing script as system

Tags: powershell, formatting, format, system

I'm trying to output some stuff to a logfile. This works perfectly fine when executing myself, but when the script is launched with SYSTEM (for example with a scheduled task) suddenly the format-table doesn't seem to be working properly and is no longer showing the full table. For example:

```
Get-WUServiceManager | Format-table -autosize | Out-File C:\Nagios\NAF\NAF_Logs\NAF_WSUS_Test.log -Append
```

Will output this when executing myself:

```
ServiceID                            IsManaged IsDefault Name                         
---------                            --------- --------- ----                         
3da21691-e39d-4da6-8a4b-b43877bcb1b7 True      True      Windows Server Update Service
9482f4b4-e343-43b6-b170-9a65bc822c77 False     False     Windows Update
```

But when the script which contains:

```
Get-WUServiceManager | Format-table -autosize | Out-File C:\Nagios\NAF\NAF_Logs\NAF_WSUS_Test.log -Append
```

is executed with a SYSTEM account I get this output:

```
ServiceID                            IsManaged IsDefault Name                  
---------                            --------- --------- ----                  
3da21691-e39d-4da6-8a4b-b43877bcb1b7 True      True      Windows Server Upda...
9482f4b4-e343-43b6-b170-9a65bc822c77 False     False     Windows Update
```

As you can see I get this "Windows Server Upd..." How can I make this work as expected under SYSTEM?

Comment: `Out-File -Width ([int]::MaxValue)`

Comment: What PerSerAl said is the reason why the output is truncated. However I recommend that you just use `Get-WUServiceManager | Select ServiceId,IsManaged,IsDefault,Name | Export-CSV -NoType C:\Nagios\NAF\NAF_Logs\NAF_WSUS_Test.log` That will get you csv output which is easier to sort and deal with.

Comment: Thanks PetSerAl. This did the trick! Do you want to submit this as answer?

Comment: You do realize that by specifying `[int]::MaxValue` for the output width you're causing each line to be padded with 2GB of whitespace, don't you? In my 64-bit, 4GB RAM ultrabook, this doesn't even produce any output (throws an OOM exception instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `-Width` parameter for `Out-File` cmdlet.

```
Get-Help Out-File -Parameter Width
```

> Specifies the number of characters in each line of output. Any additional characters are truncated, not wrapped. If you omit this parameter, the width is determined by the characteristics of the host. The default for the Windows PowerShell console is 80 (characters).

Since you run PowerShell from different account (`SYSTEM`), for which you likely never configured different default console width, `Out-File` use default width of 80 characters and truncate your output as such.

But, if you want any additional processing other than displaying data to user, then you should really read [@Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3829407) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174744#comment58069173_35174744) and use `Export-Csv` or `Export-Clixml` cmdlet.